# How to add commands to VisualStudio console?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, console

Entity Framework and Nuget both do this. They add powershell commandlets that can be launched from the visual studio package manager console.

[image: Comands in the Visual Studio Console]

It would be really great if I could write some project-centric utilities that could be committed to my source control and be available for all developers from that console.

How do I do this?

Note that I'm not looking for a 3rd party solution (eg StudioShell), and that I'm aware that I can just write normal powershell scripts to do many things. I'm interested specifically in how to write functions that are first-class citizens in the Visual Studio package manager console like `Get-Package` and `Update-Database`.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-create-custom-powershell-cmdlet-using-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Thanks @keyboardP but that is not at all it. Your link is about how to make commandlets using vs as an editor. My question is about how to make commandlets that you can use directly from the vs console (again, similar to the commands provided by EF and Nuget). As far as I remember, VS2010 didn't even have a console.

Comment: Ah apologies, I see what you mean :)

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of setting up NuGet Powershell Profile ? You create a %UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\NuGet_profile.ps1 file containing your cmdlets. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2012/06/04/installing-commands-into-the-nuget-powershell-profile

Comment: @DavidBrabant that can't be distributed along with the project so it's not how EF does it, but thanks.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer got any solution for this?

Comment: @vmassuchetto See the accepted answer. That's what I ended up doing for my [PackageManager-Drop-Db package](https://github.com/togakangaroo/Drop-Db/blob/master/tools/init.ps1). It has to be done via nuget though, no way to do it in the project itself afaik

Comment: @GeorgeMauer looks good, will try something similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EntityFramework's integration is done via NuGet, so you can't really have it in a project in your solution easily. You'd have to go through a NuGet package. Although, you could probably make it work using a local folder for the package. Essentially, EF includes a normal powershell module in its package's tools folder along with an `init.ps1` that loads the module. Its contents:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

if (Get-Module | ?{ $_.Name -eq 'EntityFramework' })
{
    Remove-Module EntityFramework
}

Import-Module (Join-Path $toolsPath EntityFramework.psd1)
```

`init.ps1` is run by NuGet/VS when opening the solution file. From the [NuGet docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package):

> Init.ps1 runs the first time a package is installed in a solution.
>     * If the same package is installed into additional projects in the solution, the script is not run during those installations.
>     * The script also runs every time the solution is opened (Package Manager Console window has to be open at the same for the script to run). For example, if you install a package, close Visual Studio, and then start Visual Studio and open the solution with Package Manager Console window, the Init.ps1 script runs again.

Comment: Thanks, so there's no way you think of actually putting that directly into a project? Darn

Comment: @GeorgeMauer The only possibility that I can think of is to have the project with the cmdlets use nuget to create a package. Then use the nuget.config at the solution level to point to a local folder. Then install from there and make sure you keep restoring/updating the package when changes are made. Seems more like a hack than a real solution though.